# I am looking for research related to the use of AI and ML in automotive and aeronautics safety design

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, reference-request

I am specifically interested in the topic of edge cases.

I have the presentation [Edge Cases and Autonomous Vehicle Safety](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/lectures/Koopman19_SSS_slides.pdf) as a starting point, in particular on page 6:

> Machine Learning (inductive training)
>
> - No design insight
> - Generally inscrutable; prone to gaming and brittleness.

I'd like to find more hard data on how ML may do very well until an edge case is encountered.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community OneArb! Are you asking for research papers or what or are you looking for suggestions for topics to research?

Comment: @nbro see my update

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I don't think that your update makes this clearer.

Comment: Hope I covered it

Comment: Now, I don't see the relationship between "I'd like to find more hard data on how ML may do very well until an edge case is encountered." and "I am looking for research related to the use of AI and ML in car, aeronautics manufacturing design and safety". Try to be a bit clearer.

Comment: See page 15: "Edge cases are the stuff you didn’t think of!" Safety will be excellent as long as the software operates within the cases covered by the training data set, very poorly otherwise.
I am looking for any study quantifying edge cases. In other words software engineers attempt to account for all possible circumstances but fail at anticipating extraordinary events. Within those edge cases ML may result in an undefined behavior, for instance accelerating where breaking was the optimal solution.

Comment: So, you should want to read about the topic, so you want just links to papers or articles that discuss these issues, right?

Comment: I am looking for any insight. I see the matter under consideration by car and areonautics manufacturers. There are hearsay accounts that ML designed systems being overall safer all together failing spectacularly outside of the "safe operation state space" where traditional software would have performed better.